# stick data and creating a quit function

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to make a program to get a student name and his mark.
e.Have to have the functionality to quit when "quit" is type and I want to stick the result with the name so for example say:
lucius F etc.

I work out the biggest part but I don't get the quit and the data tougher.

```
  #include <conio.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
        int main()
     {
     int grade;
     char name;
       looperdo:
     printf("\n \nenter student name :");
     scanf("%s",& name);
     printf(" enter estudent  score:");
     scanf("%d",&grade);
     if(grade>=0 && grade <=49)
     printf("grade=F ");
     else 
     if(grade>=50&& grade <=59)
     printf(" grade=P ");
     if(grade >=60 && grade<=69)
     printf(" grade=C");
     else
     if(grade >=70 && grade <=79)
     printf(" grade=D ");
     if(grade >=80 && grade<=100)
     printf(" grade=HD ,");
     if (grade >100 || grade <0)
     printf ("out of range , type form 0 to 100.");

     goto looperdo;

    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: This isn't C++, it's C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT USE `goto`

do a `while` loop:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  int main()
  {
     int grade;
     char name[128];
       do{
         printf("\n \nenter student name :");
         scanf("%s",&name);

         if(strcmp(name,"quit") == 0){break;} // This part is if you want to quit as soon as quit was printed

         printf(" enter estudent  score:");
         scanf("%d",&grade);

         printf("%s - ", name);//This prints the student's name

         if(grade>=0 && grade <=49)
         printf("grade=F ");
         else 
         if(grade>=50&& grade <=59)
         printf(" grade=P ");
         if(grade >=60 && grade<=69)
         printf(" grade=C");
         else
         if(grade >=70 && grade <=79)
         printf(" grade=D ");
         if(grade >=80 && grade<=100)
         printf(" grade=HD ,");
         if (grade >100 || grade <0)
         printf ("out of range , type form 0 to 100.");


     }while(name != "quit");

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: makes an error on  the line that u just change 'ISO++ for bids comparison betwen pointe and ineger"

Comment: @JAce i forgot a " sign in the if statement

Comment: yes even correcting that make that error twice line 11 & 34 ,how i make Quit like a string or moething?

Comment: @JAce don't know what error but i got seg fault. anyway edited my answer and fixed it. checked it also, you can accept my answer now by pressing the "v" sign next to the score

Comment: amazing bro sure i do